# Symfony app with redis fails in Gitlab CI

Tags: symfony, redis, gitlab-ci

I'm usin REDIS in my Symfony app and today Gitlab CI stopped working with error (after composer install and cache clear):

```
!!  In AbstractConnection.php line 155:
!!                                                                                 
!!    php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve [tcp://  
!!    redis:6379]
```

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
    - docker:dind
    - name: redis:5-alpine
      alias: redis

stages:
    - dependencies
    - build-docker

variables:
    #REDIS_PORT: 6379 - doesn't help
    #REDIS_HOST: redis - doesn't help

dependencies:
    stage: dependencies
    image: docker
    cache:
        paths:
            - bin
            - vendor
            - config/packages
            - public/bundles
        policy: push
    script:
        - sh ./run composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
    except:
        - tags
```

Gitlab CI works fine until today's morning... Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.